# Creating and Using a Fragment's View Whilst Not Visible To The User

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

**The Reason**

I need to do this because I want to get the drawable cache of the fragment's view and then create a Bitmap from that view. This Bitmap will then be used to publish on Facebook.

**The Problem**

When I create my Fragment's the views are not being created because they haven't been added via a Fragment Transaction and because the view's they contain aren't visible to the user.

I also do not want to have to draw these views manually as I will not get an exact replica of the screen.

**My Question**

Is there a way to have full functionality  (the same functionality as if you were to add it via a FragmentTransaction) of the Fragment without the fragment actually being shown?

I need to be able to access the fragment's view when it isn't visible.

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: Why do you want to get the bitmap of the fragment's view before actually adding it to the visible screen?

Comment: I want the view because I want what its displaying to convert it into a bitmap which i can then upload to Facebook

Comment: I understood that, the question was **why** the need to create that bitmap **before** the user will see it(which I'm assuming will happen at a later point when you do add the fragment to the layout)?

Comment: I don't want the user to see the fragment at all, I only want to create this fragment to get its view and then destroy it again. The fragment is another display elsewhere in the application.

Comment: Then you don't have any alternative for measuring and drawing the view yourself, that fragment it's outside of the visual screen.

Answer (score 3):

Another question addresses how to [render activities into offscreen buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604125/android-taking-screenshot-of-offscreen-page). You can use this technique to render a fragment into an offscreen buffer.

The technique involves:

- launching the new activity with startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity()
- setup a drawing cache
- use getDrawingBitmap() once layout is finished

Answer (score 1):

Does the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11061913/642680) also apply to your situation too? Basically it uses different methods of FragmentTransaction.

Comment: unfortunately not. Thanks though!

Comment: What my answer hints at is instantiating the Fragment in code and then setting its visibility with either show() or hide(). That way you have the Frgament available to you but not visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way you can just add your Fragments to a hidden layout? Example XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/GoneFragmentContainer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:visibility="gone" />
```

Then in your code:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
  .add(R.id.GoneFragmentContainer, myFragment)
  .commit();
myFragment.getView().callMethodsOnMyNonVisibleFragment();
```

Comment: I think in case the parent viewgroup has visibility=gone, the fragment's onCreateView will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid grabbing the `Bitmap` from a `View` and instead get it some other way. Then you can do whatever processing you need in the `onAttach()` method of the fragment, which gets called when you instantiate the fragment in its parent activity and it does that before it's visible.

Comment: So I'm going to have to draw it myself?

Comment: The fragment's views aren't created until the onCreateView() method. So if you want to get a bitmap from a fragment's view, that bitmap has to come from somewhere before it's put into an ImageView. I'm saying, do that "getting/processsing the bitmap from somewhere" in the onAttach() method so you might be able to get it before the fragment's view is inflated.