# How to save/Restore state of Views of fragment on Tab change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-lifecycle, fragment-tab-host

I am following [this](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/) tutorial. 
there are 3 tabs in my App. in tab3 I m making changes to some views (like buttons and EditText spinners etc) and on the behalf of these changes i have to perform some actions in tab2. Simply you can say that i Change some values in tab3 and effect takes places in tab2. I know how to do this. I just want that my values of view becomes resets every time to default values when switching between the `tab2` and `tab3`

- My question is that how can i save the states of my views. so that on resuming the tabs i must get the default look of my views as i had left previously.

One thing more i tell you that i m doing all the work in onCreateView() methos. is this correct way. like this.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onCreateView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();

if (container == null) {

    return null;
}

View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);

btnInsert = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
btnInsert.setOnClickListener(this);
btnPosition = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnPosition);
btnPosition.setOnClickListener(this);
txtPosition = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtPosition);
txtLogo = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtLogo);
imgLogoPreview = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgLogoPreview);
imgLogoPreview.setOnClickListener(this);
edTxtUserText = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.edTxtPreview);
relLogo = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.RelLogo);
relText = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.RelText);

logoWheel = (WheelView) vi.findViewById(R.id.wheelLogo);

logoWheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(logoWheelList));
logoWheel.setVisibleItems(4);
logoWheel.setCurrentItem(1);
positionWheel = (WheelView) vi.findViewById(R.id.wheelPosition);
positionWheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(
        positionWheelTextList));

// LogoWheel changed listener
changedListenerLogo = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
    public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
        if (!wheelScrolled) {

        }
    }
};

logoWheel.addChangingListener(changedListenerLogo);

// Wheel scrolled listener
scrolledListenerLogo = new OnWheelScrollListener() {

    public void onScrollStarts(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = true;

    }

    public void onScrollEnds(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = false;
        btnInsert.setText(logoWheelList[wheel.getCurrentItem()] + "");
        wheel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (wheel.getCurrentItem() == 2) {

            txtPosition.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnPosition.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            relText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            relLogo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else if (wheel.getCurrentItem() == 1) {

            relText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relLogo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtPosition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnPosition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnPosition.setText("Top");
            positionWheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(
                    positionWheelTextList));
            positionWheel.setVisibleItems(4);
            positionWheel.setCurrentItem(1);

        } else if (wheel.getCurrentItem() == 0) {

            relLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtPosition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnPosition.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnPosition.setText("Top Left");
            positionWheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(
                    positionWheelLogoList));
            positionWheel.setVisibleItems(4);
            positionWheel.setCurrentItem(1);

        }
    }
};

logoWheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListenerLogo);

// /////////////////////Positon Wheel Listners///////////

// LogoWheel changed listener
changedListenerPosition = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
    public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
        if (!wheelScrolled) {

        }
    }
};

positionWheel.addChangingListener(changedListenerPosition);

// Wheel scrolled listener
scrolledListenerPosition = new OnWheelScrollListener() {

    public void onScrollStarts(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = true;

    }

    public void onScrollEnds(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = false;

        String btnStatus = btnInsert.getText().toString();
        if (btnStatus.equals("Logo")) {
            btnPosition.setText(positionWheelLogoList[positionWheel
                    .getCurrentItem()] + "");

        } else if (btnStatus.equals("Text")) {
            btnPosition.setText(positionWheelTextList[positionWheel
                    .getCurrentItem()] + "");
        }

        wheel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
};

positionWheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListenerPosition);

return vi;
```

}

- at what point i must save the states and at what point i should retrieve the savedstates?
- Please tell me the how to implement the lifecycle of fragment in simple words.

i also tried the `saveInstance()` method of fragment. but not called.

Thanks

Comment: Please tell me the how to implement the lifecycle of fragment in simple words.

Comment: Better use ActionBar tabs for fragments as [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs).

Comment: Can you clarify, are you wanting to preserve whatever changes happen to say tab3 when it is out-of-view and altered by tab2 which *is* in view or are you wanting to set tab3 to return to default conditions once it's brought back into view?

Comment: i wan to save changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059951/how-to-preserve-fragments-recreation/11061913#11061913) might be useful. Instead of recreating Fragments each time you can hide and show them.

This of course preserves your Fragments so is possibly only something you'd do it you had a few tabs. The advantage of this is that

1. You don't need to worry about saving data and recreating the fragment
2. Changes are available immediately to the user as soon as the relevant tab is selected.